# Shorter ellipsis

Tags: spacing, ellipsis, decimal-number

In LaTeX `\ldots` gives dots which are spaced out properly for most uses in text and math. However, when placed after a decimal expansion, I find them too spaced out. Using `3.14...` instead of `3.14\ldots` does not look nice either (too packed). Is there a special command for decimal approximation ellipsis?

Here is the output of `\pi = 3.14\ldots = 3.14...` (above: display, below: inline)

[image: above: display, below: inline]

Update: as suggested by David Carlisle, I tried `3.14{\ldots}` and it looks slightly better:

[image: putting ldots between braces]

Comment: You can use `...`  which is tighter, or `{\ldots}` which is mathord so less space after the 4.  In `unicode-math`, `\ldots` uses `…` (U+2026) so spacing depends on the font but tends to be tighter than classic tex three spaced `.` definition

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle. Unicode-math does not seem compatible with pdflatex, so I will have to tweak my IDE (these days this is texstudio) to give it a try.

Comment: it needs lualatex or xelatex

Comment: I managed to make XeLaTeX work with texstudio. Now I would need to experiment with different fonts, I may if I have time. Independently (without unicode-math), I tried {\dots} as you suggest and this gives a slightly better looking result indeed, thanks.

Comment: (Not tested.)  Extending @DavidCarlisle's suggestion, you might apply brute force, and treat each dot individually -- `{.}{.}{.}` -- which will leave only the space provided by side bearings.  This may be closer to what you want, or may not, and is likely to be different depending on the font you're using.  But I suspect it won't be as tight as what's nominally provided by the single Unicode character.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. I just tested `{.}{.}{.}` and could not see a difference with `...`